# Display only Allow Values for User in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following tables

```
public class Area
{
    public int AreaId {get;set;}
    public string AreaName {get;set;}   
}

public class User_AREA
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public int AreaId {get;set;}
}


public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public int AreaId {get;set;}
    public string CustomerName {get;set;}
}
```

I want to make Linq Query to give result : display all allow   customers for selected/login user in Linq

```
var list = _customerService.GetAllCustomer(int UserId) {}
```

Comment: Do you use Linq to SQL ? Entity framework ? Or How do you query the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a context object called `db`:

```
private List<Customer> GetAllCustomer(int UserId)
{
    var CustomersByUser = (from a in db.User_AREA
                          join c in db.Customer
                          on a.AreaId equals c.AreaId
                          where a.UserId = UserId
                          select c).ToList();

    return CustomersByUser;
}
```

The above joins the two tables and returned only the customer that share the same area as the user passed to the method using the `UserId` Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all customer then by where filter it.for example,

```
 var list= _wheelingService.GetAllCustomer().Where(i=>User_AREA.Any(p=>p.AreaId ==i.AreaId && p.UserId==UserId);
```

> thanks its working to but you forgot to add p.UserId==UserId